# Grails unit testing domain classes with Set properties - is this safe?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, dns

I've created a domain class in Grails like this:

```
class MyObject {
    static hasMany = [tags: String]
    // Have to declare this here, as nullable constraint does not seem to be honoured
    Set tags = new HashSet() 

    static constraints = {
        tags(nullable: false)
    }
}
```

Writing unit tests to check the size and content of the MyObject.tags property, I found I had to do the following:

```
assertLength(x, myObject.tags as Object[])
assertEquals(new HashSet([...]), myObject.tags)
```

To make the syntax nicer for writing the tests, I implemented the following methods:

```
void assertEquals(List expected, Set actual) {
    assertEquals(new HashSet(expected), actual)
}

void assertLength(int expected, Set set) {
    assertLength(expected, set as Object[])
}
```

I can now call the assertLength() and assertEquals() methods directly on an instance of Set, e.g.
    assertLength(x, myObject.tags)
    assertEquals([...], myObject.tags)

I'm new to Groovy and Grails, so unaware how dangerous method overloading like this is.  Is it safe?  If so, I'm slightly* surprised that these methods (or similar) aren't already available - please let me know if they are.

---

`*` I can see how these methods could also introduce ambiguity if people weren't expecting them.  E.g. `assertLength(1, set)` always passes, no matter what the content of `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't seem to be any problems with the approach outlined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me

The [Definitive Guide to Grails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597583) book (which admittedly is 2006), it says to do it with:

```
assertLength( 1, myObject.tags as Object[] )
```

or using the size() method like:

```
assertEquals( 1, myObject.tags.size() )
```

Comment: Ok, that's how I'm doing assertLength() inside the method.  I'd be interested to know if use of a method like this would be discouraged.

Also, any thoughts on my assertEquals() method?